# PHP DateTime->format incorrect month

Tags: php

This code:

```
$expDateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/y', '04/19');
echo $expDateObj->format('Y-m');

echo "<br/>";

$expDateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/y', '05/19');
echo $expDateObj->format('Y-m');
```

produces this result:

```
2019-05
2019-05
```

Why is that?

**Edit**
I'm getting the above with PHP 7.0 on http://phptester.net/

Comment: https://3v4l.org/NclBo apparently it is not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the day part of a date is missing, PHP will default the missing day to the current day. Today is 31st July, so it will use `31` as the day, giving `31st April 2019` for your `04-19` entry... which doesn't exist, so it's rolled over to `1st May 2017`. Hence, your final result of `2019-05`.

You can force PHP to default the missing day to the first day of the month (`01`) rather than the current day by changing your mask slightly:

```
$expDateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/y|', '04/19');
echo $expDateObj->format('Y-m');
```